# How to set a start date for a new date column, and link it to time to change to the next day

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a dataset which has only recorded time but not date, as so:

```
>accel
UTC.Time Milliseconds X.Acc Y.Acc Z.Acc Temp
23:59:59          813  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 
23:59:59          844  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 
23:59:59          875  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 
23:59:59          906  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0
23:59:59          938  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 
23:59:59          969  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0
00:00:00            0  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 
00:00:00           31  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 
00:00:00           63  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 
00:00:00           94  0.31 -0.81 -0.50    0 
00:00:00          125  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 
00:00:00          156  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0
```

I know when my dataset starts ("2015/03/15") and can add a date column using:

```
>  m<-paste("03")
>  d<-paste("05")
>  accel$UTC.Date<-paste("2015/",m,"/",d,"", sep="")
```

I have numerous dates for different files, hence I have set up up like this, but this create a new UTC.Date column with dates as:

```
>accel
UTC.Time Milliseconds X.Acc Y.Acc Z.Acc Temp UTC.Date
23:59:59          813  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
23:59:59          844  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
23:59:59          875  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
23:59:59          906  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
23:59:59          938  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
23:59:59          969  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
00:00:00            0  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
00:00:00           31  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
00:00:00           63  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
00:00:00           94  0.31 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
00:00:00          125  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
00:00:00          156  0.25 -0.81 -0.50    0 2015/03/05
```

The problem here, is that my date has not switched to 2015/03/06 with midnight, 00:00:00. How can I set a start date and ensure it matches with time and changes as we cross into the next day?

I have different numbers of samples for each day so cannot set an interval, for example.

I have tried

```
accel$UTC.Datetime<- strptime(as.character(accel$UTC.Time),format="%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
```

which gives todays' date and the given time but still does not change the date at midnight:

```
>accel$UTC.Datetime
2020-12-21 23:59:59
2020-12-21 23:59:59
2020-12-21 23:59:59
2020-12-21 23:59:59
2020-12-21 23:59:59
2020-12-21 00:00:00
2020-12-21 00:00:00
2020-12-21 00:00:00
2020-12-21 00:00:00
2020-12-21 00:00:00
```

Is there a 'start' or 'origin' option I am missing? Any help with this is much appreciated

Comment: Midnight, i.e. when the date change happens, is `23:59:59` to `00:00:00` not from `00:00:00` to `00:00:01`, isn't it?

Comment: That is very true, I selected a subsection of my code to represent here but copied the wrong section. I am encountering the error just the same. I have re-imported my examples to reflect this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, we may format the time column without date `as.POSIXct` which adds the `Sys.Date` to it. Now, we have everywhere `st.dt` prefixed.

As second step, to obtain date switches plus one after midnight, we coerce the original `UTC.Time` column to numerics by removing the `:` and count where the differences are smaller than, say `-200000` (depends on your time steps). The `cumsum` of those, multiplied by the seconds of a day, added to the dates of the first step, give us the desired result.

```
st.dt <- "2015-03-05"  ## start date
dat <- within(dat,{
  UTC.Datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(UTC.Time, Milliseconds, sep="."),
                             format="%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC") -
    (as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), tz="UTC") - as.POSIXct(st.dt, tz="UTC")) + 
    cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", UTC.Time)))) < -200000)*86400 
})
dat
# U   TC.Time Milliseconds X.Acc Y.Acc Z.Acc Temp        UTC.Datetime
# 1  23:59:59          813  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-05 23:59:59
# 2  23:59:59          844  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-05 23:59:59
# 3  23:59:59          875  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-05 23:59:59
# 4  00:00:00          906  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-06 00:00:00
# 5  00:00:00          938  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-06 00:00:00
# 6  00:00:00          969  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-06 00:00:00
# 7  00:00:01            0  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-06 00:00:01
# 8  00:00:01           31  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-06 00:00:01
# 9  00:00:01           63  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-06 00:00:01
# 10 00:00:01           94  0.31 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-06 00:00:01
# 11 23:59:59          125  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-06 23:59:59
# 12 00:00:01          156  0.25 -0.81  -0.5    0 2015-03-07 00:00:01
```

And it's fast:

```
dat <- dat[sample(nrow(dat), 1e6, replace=T), ]
dim(dat)
# [1] 1000000       7
system.time(<code above>)
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.03    0.05    3.16
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(UTC.Time = c("23:59:59", "23:59:59", "23:59:59", 
"00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:01", "00:00:01", "00:00:01", 
"00:00:01", "00:00:01", "00:00:01"), Milliseconds = c(813L, 844L, 
875L, 906L, 938L, 969L, 0L, 31L, 63L, 94L, 125L, 156L), X.Acc = c(0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.31, 0.25, 0.25
), Y.Acc = c(-0.81, -0.81, -0.81, -0.81, -0.81, -0.81, -0.81, 
-0.81, -0.81, -0.81, -0.81, -0.81), Z.Acc = c(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 
-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5), Temp = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: This is great and works! It is quite slow though, it jams my computer for a couple of minutes. I am processing hundreds of files, is there a quicker way to achieve this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CED Found a solution that is around ten times faster! See edits.